# Custom routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I´m new to rails and don´t know much about routing. Maybe it is a silly question or already answered.

What i want to do is, I have (music) Genres and artists. When I click to show more about genre it redirects me to show.html.erb, when I click to show artists in genre, I am redirected to  Artists index page.

I created a footer in my app, from which i want to access all artists in database, not just for genre which artist belongs to. I want to use existing controller.

In my artists controller i have function,

```
def all_artists
  @artists = Artist.all
end
```

I want to create some all_artists.html.erb which cooperates with function in controller like #index or #show do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a **Collection Routes**.
Add it in your artist restful resource, in the routes file:

```
resources :artists do
  collection do
    get 'all_artists'
  end
end
```

That code adds the route `/artists/all_artist`, that calls the controller methods `all_artists`.
The route name and the controller method could have different name, for example:

```
get 'all', :as => '#all_artists'
```

In this case /artists/all_artist links with artists#all_artist.

I hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Routing in Rails takes more than just a few words to explain, but luckily [there is a really good/easy to follow article on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You should only need to read the start to get the info you need. Towards the end it deals with more complicated situations but it's the easiest to follow explanation I've ever seen.